# Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: android, gradle, runtime-error

I'm getting the following warning

> Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for
>   debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by
>   Android. In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

The dependency "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2" is not even in my gradle file.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should exclude `commons-logging` from any dependency that includes it. It's gonna be like this:

```
compile ('<name-of-the-package-that-has-as-dependency-commons-logging>') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

Comment: As in this example that I am using to guard against org.apache.httpcomponents:

    `code' compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android'
     compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-  android' , version: '4.3.5.1') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile files('libs/common-lang3.jar')
`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {   
 compileSdkVersion 22    
 buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"    
 defaultConfig {        
 applicationId "com.milople.useraudio"        
 minSdkVersion 15        
 targetSdkVersion 22       
 versionCode 1       
 versionName "1.0"       
 multiDexEnabled true    
}  
  packagingOptions {        
             exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'      
             exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'      
  }   
 buildTypes {        
            release {            
                 minifyEnabled true            
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'       
 }   
 }      
compileOptions {          
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7      
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7    
}}
buildscript {    
repositories{ 
           maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }           
}
dependencies {       
 classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'    
}}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'repositories { 
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }}
dependencies {    
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])    
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0+'   
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'    
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'    
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.9.8.jar')   
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'    
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'    
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'     
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.7.2@aar') {
transitive = true;    
}    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'    
compile 'com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.6@aar'   
compile 'com.dwolla:dwolla-java-sdk:2.0.5'   
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'  
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'  
}
```