# Dependency is ignored for debug after adding AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, build.gradle

On adding

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.0'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.0'
```

to my build.gradle, I get the error `Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.`

Per [Android dependency is ignored for release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295066/android-dependency-is-ignored-for-release) and [Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262912/dependency-commons-loggingcommons-logging1-2-is-ignored-for-debug-as-it-may-be) and a few others, I have added

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.0'  { exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging' }
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.0' { exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging' }
```

but now I am getting the error

`Error:(34, 0) Could not find method com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.0() for arguments [build_4hd82gce5nfvqpzrlv6x687px$_run_closure2$_closure7@38039d7e] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\[PATH]\build.gradle">Open File</a>`

I have not been able to find any suggestions as to what to do about this.

It might also be worth noting that I am still setting up the UI; other than this, I don't think I have actually added any code beyond what Android Studio auto generates.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
```

Comment: If I do that and leave the exclude in, I get the same "Could not find method" error. If I take out the exclude, I get "Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds."